# Can I have a sidegig contract in the US if im fully employed in the UK?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, self-employment, contractor

My current situation is the following:

1. I'm based in the UK.
2. I'm working as a full time employee for a company X that has a client Y.
3. We've finished some work for client Y and they have a US company that they work with, company Z.
4. Company Z asked me if I wanted to do do a side-gig with them, a few hours here and there.

My question is the following:

Could I have a setup where I don't have to declare the money in the UK? I don't mind not having access to it if that's an issue (i.e. I don't want to spend the money I earn overseas in the UK)?

What's the setup that people follow for those kinds of gigs? I'm not sure what search terms I need to google.

Comment: Working, but not having access to your money?

Comment: im thinking the way you setup a company in the uk where you pay dividents as your salary. Im OK without paying anything to myself, hence the 'not having access'

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/taxed-twice That's the normal tax treatment - you live and work in the UK, so you pay taxes on all income there, and can request tax relief if you are double-taxed (i.e., if the US requires any taxes paid). Overseas tax avoidance schemes are common for large companies and millionaires (complicated accounting that claims losses where taxes are due and shifts profits to low-tax jurisdictions), but they are rarely available or affordable enough to regular folks - cost too much to be worth it, ethics aside.